# Making a Text element both Swipeable and Pressable in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have the following component:

```
<Swipeable renderRightActions={console.log('SWIPED')}>
   <Pressable onLongPress={(evt)=> props.longPress(evt)} onPressOut={(evt) => props.press(evt)}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Pressable</Text>
   </Pressable>
</Swipeable>
```

The `Pressable` events, `onLongPress()` and `onPressOut()` occur as expected. However, the `Swipeable` event is called not when the user swipes on the `Text` element, but rather on both `onLongPress()` and `onPressOut()`. If `Pressable` is commented out, `Swipeable` does nothing.

What is the correct way in React Native to make a `Text` element swipeable, while at the same time capturing the press events?

Thanks very much

Comment: Any news on this one ?